# Replace 0 in array with "null" word in array

Tags: c#

I have a List that is converted to a string for JSON parsing. I need to replace 0 values with the word "null" since the API that I'm using accepts it rather than leaving it blank it the list.

I tried string replace "0," with "null," however this will not work when the end of the list value is 0.

```
public List<double> Message { get; set; }

public string jsonMessage
    get {
        string test = "";
    if (this.Message!= null && this.Message.Count > 0)
    {
        test = String.Join(",", this.Message).Replace("0,","null,")
    }
    return test; 
}
```

Comment: What has this got to do with JavaScript?

Comment: can you provide test data.. or values present in `Message`

Comment: Why dont you replace the values in the list before creating the string?

Comment: Are you sure that's JSON?

Comment: You don't need the message count check; string join returns an empty string if there are zero elements in your list

Comment: This would also replace values like `20` with `2null`, won't it?

Comment: Carefull with double and comma separated value based on server culture double may have comma as decimal separator.

Answer (score 5):

I believe this should accomplish what you're describing:

```
test = string.Join(",", Message.Select(n => n == 0 ? "null" : n.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you have called that property `jsonMessage`, do you trying to construct json by hand or something? But anyway, you can simply do:

```
test = String.Join(",", this.Message.Select(s => s == 0 ? "null" : s.ToString()));
```